# Cannot extract .tgz file dowloaded from magento

Tags: magento

I found a issue with magento. I tried to upload one .tgz zipped file to magento by compressing it along with another pdf file. However when I try to download it from magento the .tgz file becomes corrupted. I have seen this in 4-5 different occasions with different files Hence I thought it as issue with Magento ? However it works great just by extracting the zip file into PC.

Just let me know the possible reason and solution for this.

Comment: "Hence I thought it as issue with However"? Also punctuation would help the readers.

Comment: check that file whether corrupted or not, via FTP into that magento location folder.

Comment: FYI: Magento 2 has the opposite problem: with Downloadable product: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/downloadable-zip-files-are-corrupt

Answer (score 0):

how about downloading that zipped file via FTP.
Maybe there was an interruption while you were downloading the file via browser

Comment: Actually my customers  will download the file that will be linked to the downloadable product in magento. The so called .tgz file is attched with specific downlodable products

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the problem you are experiencing is due in part to the way Magento is generating (possibly incorrect) HTTP-Headers for compressed items. The end result is that items can become corrupted because they might get double compressed, however, there are some simple things you can do if in fact this appears to be issue you are experiencing.

1. Do not use `SetOutputFilter DEFLATE`
2. Do not use `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php`
3. Create exception rules as needed with `SetEnvIfNoCase`

All of this is [explained in more detail by Babs Gösgens](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-performance/654-compressing-magento-output), who was also kind enough to provide a Magento `.htaccess` template that includes definitions for handling some of these issues:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript application/x-javascript
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php

    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:pdf|doc)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:avi|mov|mp3|mp4|rm)$ no-gzip dont-vary

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not the problem with magento. Its the header problem. Also how you are downloading the file ? have you given direct link for download ? if yes then remove that and write an custom action to download that something like

```
public function downloadFileAction() {
        ignore_user_abort ( true );
        set_time_limit ( 0 ); // disable the time limit for this script

        $fullPath = Mage::getBaseDir () . "path_to_your_file/yourFile.tgz";

        if ($fd = fopen ( $fullPath, "r" )) {
            $fsize = filesize ( $fullPath );
            $path_parts = pathinfo ( $fullPath );
            $ext = strtolower ( $path_parts ["extension"] );
            switch ($ext) {
                case 'tgz':
                    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                    header('Content-Length: ' . $fsize);
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $path_parts ["basename"]);
                    readfile($fullPath);
                default :
                    header ( "Content-type: application/octet-stream" );
                    header ( "Content-Disposition: filename=\"" . $path_parts ["basename"] . "\"" );
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

and call your action like :

```
$this->getUrl('your_controler') ?>index/downloadFile
```

Hope this will help you